# How to show row sub total as value for each row as separate column on power bi

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, visualization

How to show row sub total as value for each row as separate column on power bi

Say I have a table

```
Product price  day
A       45      1
A       53      1
A       60      2
B       50      1
B       67      1
B       40      2
B       50      2
```

Logic for representation

```
Product price  day
A       45      1
A       53      1
A       60      2
Total    38
B       50      1
B       30      1
B       40      2
B       50      2    
Total.  10
```

Basically total is measure doing calculation for day 2-day 1

How i want to represent

Product prior-price  day change
A       45            1     38
A       53            1     38
A       60            2     38
B       50            1     10
B       67            1     10
B       40            2     10
B       50            2     10

Answer (score 0):

First, you must compute the sum for each product for Day 1 and Day 2.
Then, compute the difference between the Day 2 sum and Day 1 sum.
Finally, associate that difference with each product in the main table.

```
Change = 
VAR ProductDay1Sum = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[price]),
        FILTER('Table', 'Table'[day] = 1 && 'Table'[Product] = EARLIER('Table'[Product]))
    )
VAR ProductDay2Sum = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[price]),
        FILTER('Table', 'Table'[day] = 2 && 'Table'[Product] = EARLIER('Table'[Product]))
    )
RETURN
    ProductDay2Sum - ProductDay1Sum
```

Comment: Product  is not limited to 2 only so does the change in price and day

Comment: Can you explain better your situation then ?